# Smoothly changing text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a landing page where a phrase is constantly changing with select words.  For instance,

> Design better websites
>   made for clients.

will switch the first or last word to become

> Develop better websites
>   made for clients.

However, since "Develop" is a larger word than "Design", the rest of the text ends up getting pushed around without smoothly transitioning.  Keep in mind, this is a multi-line sentence, and it is centered.

```js
var first  = ['Create','Design','Develop'];
var second = ['you','clients','artists','us'];
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var maxfirst  = first.length - 1;
var maxsecond = second.length - 1;

function delay() {
    $('#intro').velocity("transi1ion.slideUpIn", 1250);
    setInterval(firstwordchange, 400);
    setInterval(secondwordchange, 500);
}

function firstwordchange() {
    if (i < maxfirst) i++; else i = 0;

    $('#firstword').velocity("transition.slideUpOut", 300);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#firstword').text(first[i]);
    }, 200);

  $('#firstword').velocity("transition.slideUpIn", 300);
}

function secondwordchange() {
    if (j < maxsecond) j++; else j = 0;

    $('#secondword').velocity("transition.slideUpOut", 300);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#secondword').text(second[j]);
    }, 200);

    $('#secondword').velocity("transition.slideUpIn", 300);
}

setTimeout(delay, 700);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.1.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.1.0/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="intro">
    <span id="firstword" class="introchange">Create</span>
    better websites made for
    <span id="secondword" class="introchange">you</span>.
</div>
```

How can I make the inner, non-changing text transition smoothly?

([actual website here](http://puu.sh/dv5Mw/240ae435ca.png))

Comment: Determine the length of the longest first word and offset the main sentence by that much. There isn't really a better way to do it, without the jittery looking text.

Comment: Wouldn't that create an ugly gap when a shorter word was used?  I'm looking more towards an option that will move the internal text smoothly, since this is very much in need of communicating good design.

Comment: Put the first word in a fixed-width container and right-align it.

Comment: That was my initial thought - I might do that if nothing else works out, but I have the text centered on the website, so I'd like to keep it in the middle as much as possible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oz3zcrsh/1/

Comment: That's a good answer for 1 line text, unfortunately I have multiline.  I should edit my question to include that.

Comment: Any creative solutions here will be more about design than programming.

Comment: I think you should ask this in http://ux.stackexchange.com/. Once you know the best solution, if you have problems implementing it, you can ask here.

Comment: @Oriol, I know exactly what I want.  I just forgot to mention a few things, which I'm editing now.   I need the text to smoothly transition instead of jumping.

Comment: http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/hwAuJ

Comment: Give the first and last words a definite length using CSS, and the length of the word is the longest possible word, (like "develop")

Since the words are in beginning and end, you can justify the first word right and last word left (and include period as part of the last word), and since you are designing a landing page, I assume your text will be centered so there won't be huge leading space for short leading words.

Comment: Isn't there CSS Animation? Seems it would work better. Especially since the Javascript animation I've seen is slow, clunky and uses 100% of the CPU. On mobile I wish it would die. That includes laptops with i7 CPUs. 100%! What are JS devs smoking?

Comment: @ChrisMartin I checked out your code and it seems to be working well. There is one problem that I've not been able to figure out. When you switch tabs and revisit the page after a few seconds, the transitions try to catch up quickly and occur very fast. Is there a way to not let this happen?

Comment: @AyrtonSenna You may want to ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm going to write an outline of how I <del>would do</del> did it:

1. Render the sentence using default initial values for the changing words and static positioning.
2. Also render the other word variants with `visibility: hidden` so that you can determine their sizes.
3. [Absolutize](http://api.jquery.com/position/) every sentence part. From this point on everything will be absolutely positioned so it's best if you have a nice positioning context around it (usually done with `position: relative` on the parent).
4. Measure every sentence part, both changing words and fixed sentence parts widths, including the hidden ones.
5. When changing the words compute the differences between the old sizes and the new ones. Based on those differences, use some very simple Math to see how much parts should move left or right and apply a horizontal translation on them (and of course animate the translation - possibly just for what you want moving left/right, maybe you want other effects for the changing words).

**Demo:**

```js
var first = ['Create','Cut','Reticulate'];
var second = ['you','clients','artists','us'];
var firstM = [], secondM = [], el;

var $first = $('.the-first'); 
var $second = $('.the-second'); 
var $container = $('#container');

// init static //    
$first.text(first[0]);
$second.text(second[0]);

// create measurables //
for(var i = 0; i < first.length; i++){
    el = $('<div class="measurable">' + first[i] + '</div>');
    $container.append(el);
    firstM.push(el.width());
}
for(var i = 0; i < second.length; i++){
    el = $('<div class="measurable">' + second[i] + '</div>');
    $container.append(el);
    secondM.push(el.width());
}

// absolutize //
var positions = [];
$('#container > span').each(function(){
    positions.push($(this).position());
});
$('#container > span').each(function(){
    var pos = positions.shift();
    $(this).css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: pos.left,
        top: pos.top
    });
});

// remember initial sizes //
var firstInitialWidth = $first.width();
var secondInitialWidth = $second.width();

// loop the loop //
var activeWordsIndex = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    activeWordsIndex++;
    var firstIndex = activeWordsIndex % first.length;
    var secondIndex = activeWordsIndex % second.length;
    
    $first.text( first[firstIndex] );
    $second.text( second[secondIndex] );
    
    var firstLineOffset = (firstM[firstIndex] - firstInitialWidth) / 2;
    var secondLineOffset = (secondM[secondIndex] - secondInitialWidth) / 2;
   
    $('.static.first').css({
        transform: 'translateX(' + firstLineOffset + 'px)'
    });
    $('.static.second').css({
        transform: 'translateX(' + (-secondLineOffset) + 'px)'
    });
    
    $first.css({
        transition: 'none', 
        transform: 'translate(' + (-firstLineOffset) + 'px, -30px)',
        opacity: '0'
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $first.css({
            transition: 'all 1s ease',
            transform: 'translate(' + (-firstLineOffset) + 'px, 0px)',
            opacity: '1'
        });
    }, 50);
    
    $second.css({
        transition: 'none', 
        transform: 'translate(' + (-secondLineOffset) + 'px, 30px)',
        opacity: '0'
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $second.css({
            transition: 'all 1s ease',
            transform: 'translate(' + (-secondLineOffset) + 'px, 0px)',
            opacity: '1'
        });
    }, 50);
}, 2000);
```

```css
#ubercontainer {
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #ffefc6;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #4a6b82;
    height: 78px;
}
.measurable {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.static.first, .static.second {
    transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ubercontainer">
<div id="container">
    <span class="the-first"></span> 
    <span class="static first">better websites </span><br />
    <span class="static second">made for</span> 
    <span class="the-second"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks really great! I think that this would be a really nice banner for a website! But just wondering myself if you can't use `$.animate` instead of all those `$.css` to achieve the same effect. Probably you won't for the `translate()` style, but you can for the opacity (which will shim the `opacity` style for IE8>). But I like how it looks like!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Note that I have there a rough demo. Also I wouldn't use jQuery at all for this since it's not needed, but I wrote it at 5 am and didn't have the patience to make everything nice and clean.

Comment: Don't worry about that, it was just a detail. But your code looks nice. I would probably set the css for the `.measurable`s and the `.static`'s on the code itself instead on the css. This may cause problems when used on other pages where people come here and simply copy-paste the whole content and then ask why it doesn't work. Doe to the easiness of jQuery, you can chain this all in no trouble! I can rewrite this as a plugin later on, if you want.

Answer (score 10):

Writing a solution like this you will quickly come to realize you will have to abandon the idea of dynamic line breaks if your words differ in length by a reasonable amount.

That small detail aside, you can easily achieve the effect you're after using a standard pyramid of jQuery animate callback hell:

```js
var target = $('#target');
var change = function(str) {
  var tmp = $('<h1>' + str + '</h1>');
  tmp.css({
      display: "inline-block",
      position: "absolute"
    })
    .appendTo('body')
    .hide();
  var targetWidth = tmp.outerWidth();
  tmp.remove();
  target.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 200, function() {
    target.animate({
      width: targetWidth
    }, 300, function() {
      target.empty()
        .html(str)
        .css({
          display: "initial"
        })
        .animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, 200);
    });
  });
}
var samples = [
  "some sample",
  "another example",
  "just"
];
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  change(samples[++i % samples.length]);
}, 1400);
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#target {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: no-wrap;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is <span id="target"></span> text</h1>
  <h1>in a longer sentence</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using the Web Animation API

```
Element.animate();
```

Simplest reference: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36

Answer (score 2):

Got some good answers.
Alin Purcaru has a much better and more coherently-written answer, but I thought I'd provide my own.

Nit had what I was looking for, but since I'm not the best programmer, I tried to come up with a solution I could understand.  After an hour or two, [here's what I got.](http://jsfiddle.net/oz3zcrsh/19/)

Basically, I'm comparing the full block of text to the parent element, finding the space between them, halving it, and then applying that as a negative margin to the text.  I can transition this with CSS since I'm moving a full block.

Here's a very bad drawing in MSpaint to illustrate my point

[image]

the text has `display: inline-block` so the div fits to the text rather than taking up 100% of the parent.

Since I was transition with CSS in my javascript, all I needed to do to make it smooth was

```
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Pro tip: Don't use margins, use translations. The animations on them are more efficient.

Comment: Translations?  I'm not familiar.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I'll implement those.