# Jquery - animating parent's width smoothly after changing child's(span) text.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I am wondering how to change parent's width(button) SMOOTHLY - without immediately jumping width after changing child's(span) text. [Here's the jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fz4xya60/) Thanks!

HTML:

```
<button><span>Hi</span></button>
```

jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("button span").text("Hello World!!");
});
```

Comment: Repeated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476283/smoothly-changing-text-with-javascript

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi No, I meant something else. I updated a question, can you look at it again please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a width css transition, and put the new text and old text in spans that are toggled when the button is clicked.
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grt812/fz4xya60/36/

```
HTML:
<button>
  <span id="firstspan">Hi</span>
  <span id="secondspan">Hello World!!</span>
</button>

CSS:
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
button {
  overflow: hidden;
  width:35px;
  transition: width 2s;
}

JQuery:
$(function() {
  $("#secondspan").hide();
  $("button").one("click", function() {
    $("button").css("width", "90px");
    $("#firstspan").toggle();
    $("#secondspan").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I tried transition: all 0.5s; and it didn't work. Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: @Null No problem :)